# C#. VisualStudio. Flujo de Programa

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema para resolver: Es de C# y con VisualStudio:
Escribe un programa que muestre  en pantalla “Feliz cumpleaños” repetido tantas veces como años tenga.
¿algún alma caritativa me podría explicar que código poner? Intuyo que tengo que generar un bucle while pero no consigo dar con ello.

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que intentaste??? y tengamos en cuenta que vos lo queres en c#.. visual studio es una ide, el programa que usas para programar en c#.. pero podes programar en c# en cualquier lado, inclusive en notepad...

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema. muy bien ya entendiste que tenes que usar un bucle.. ahora cual es el problema?

Comment: te daré una respuesta que sea igual de consisa que tu pregunta: haz un ciclo que imprima el mensaje que quieres las veces que necesitaba

Comment: Que codigo has intentado? porque un while y no un for que iteres ese numero de años

Answer (score -1):

Yo usaría un ciclo for:

Primero, declaramos la variable con el `string` que buscas repetir

```
string cadena = "Feliz cumple";
```

Luego creamos el ciclo e introducimos la variable:

```
for(int indice = 0; indice < 10; indice++){
  Console.WriteLine(cadena);
}
```

Esto te imprimirá 10 veces tu string, para la próxima deberías poner lo que has probado y algo de código sino te cerrarán la pregunta.

Comment: tratamos enfaticamente de no contestar preguntas que sean solo enunciados de ejercicios... si no, siempre se hace lo mismo :(

Comment: Me parece bien, lo respeto. No le di la respuesta completa, solo lo guié con un ejemplo de cómo puede hacerlo. Aunque entiendo tu punto @gbianchi

Comment: estas preguntas se suelen cerrar aproximadamente una hora despues de que se abren.. si OP no agrega nada...

Comment: Pues borro la respuesta, ¿Te parece? Para evitar inconvenientes en la comunidad

Comment: Tampoco hay que ponerse así chico...controla el Ego gbianchi que si nos dejamos llevar por él nos lo hace pasar muy mal...

Comment: Muchas gracias Franqo

Comment: @CóndorLegítimo si la respuesta te ha servido, por favor no olvides marcarla como correcta